# powershell script that outputs date of the day as a file name

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, powershell, scripting

I have a script which lists local admins of all hosts in Active Directory below:

```
$Searcher = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([ADSI]"")
$Searcher.Filter = "(objectClass=computer)"
$Computers = ($Searcher.Findall())
md C:\All_Local_Admins
Foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
$Path=$Computer.Path
$Name=([ADSI]"$Path").Name
write-host $Name
$members =[ADSI]"WinNT://$Name/Administrators"
$members = @($members.psbase.Invoke("Members"))
$members | foreach {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty',
$null, $_, $null) | out-file -append C:\All_Local_Admins\$name.txt
}
}
```

This script outputs HOST machine names as txt files (HOST1.txt, HOST2.txt etc)

What I want is to get a single text file whose name gets the date of the day (for example: 05082014.txt  --> This file will include local admins of all hosts)

How can I manage this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

You could do this:

```
$fileName = (Get-Date -Format ddMMyyyy) + ".txt"
$location = "C:\All_Local_Admins\"
New-Item -ItemType file -Name $fileName -Path $location
```

And replace your `out-file` with this:

```
out-file -append -FilePath (Join-Path $location $fileName)
```

Comment: Nice. You could replace `$location\$fileName` with `(Join-Path $location $fileName)` to prevent a missing trailing slash if somebody else updates the `$location`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I edited the answer. Thanks for the tip.